# Migration ExtJS from 3 to 5

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs5

I plan to migrate all my applications which are developed with Sencha ExtJS 3.x
The target release is version 5.x

Is there any migration guide for this kind of case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are guides from 3 -> 4 and then 4 -> 5 would be much more straightforward. I will warn you that 3 -> 4 is not an easy task for a large application.

Comment: Completely agree with this. +1